# Having trouble mapping existing events from the database in react fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fullcalendar

I am having trouble in mapping database columns with the event fields to display. I am trying to add my get call inside Util.

```
----Event.jsx-----
import React from "react";
import FullCalendar, { formatDate } from "@fullcalendar/react";
import dayGridPlugin from "@fullcalendar/daygrid";
import timeGridPlugin from "@fullcalendar/timegrid";
import interactionPlugin from "@fullcalendar/interaction";
import { INITIAL_EVENTS, createEventId } from "./Util";

export default class EventCalander extends React.Component {
  state = {
    weekendsVisible: true,
    currentEvents: [],
  };


  render() {
    return (
      <div className="demo-app">
        {this.renderSidebar()}
        <div className="demo-app-main">
          <FullCalendar
            plugins={[dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, interactionPlugin]}
            headerToolbar={{
              left: "prev,next today",
              center: "title",
              right: "dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay",
              
            }}
            initialView="timeGridWeek"
            editable={true}
            selectable={true}
            selectMirror={true}
            dayMaxEvents={true}
            weekends={this.state.weekendsVisible}
            initialEvents={ INITIAL_EVENTS } // alternatively, use the `events` setting to fetch from a feed
            select={this.handleDateSelect}
            eventContent={renderEventContent} // custom render function
            eventClick={this.handleEventClick}
            eventsSet={this.handleEvents} // called after events are initialized/added/changed/removed
            /* you can update a remote database when these fire: 
            eventAdd={async function()}
            eventChange={function()}
            eventRemove={function() }*/
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

  renderSidebar() {
    return (
      <div className="demo-app-sidebar">
         <div className='demo-app-sidebar-section'>
            <h2>Instructions</h2>
            <ul>
              <li>Select dates and you will be prompted to create a new event</li>
              <li>Drag, drop, and resize events</li>
              <li>Click an event to delete it</li>
            </ul>
          </div> 
        <div className="demo-app-sidebar-section">
           <label>
              <input
                type='checkbox'
                checked={this.state.weekendsVisible}
                onChange={this.handleWeekendsToggle}
              ></input>
              toggle weekends
            </label> 
        </div>
        <div className="demo-app-sidebar-section">
          <h2>All Events ({this.state.currentEvents.length})</h2>
          <ul>{this.state.currentEvents.map(renderSidebarEvent)}</ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

  handleWeekendsToggle = () => {
    this.setState({
      weekendsVisible: !this.state.weekendsVisible,
    });
  };

  handleDateSelect = (selectInfo) => {
    let title = prompt("Please enter a new title for your event");
    let calendarApi = selectInfo.view.calendar;

    calendarApi.unselect(); // clear date selection

    if (title) {
      calendarApi.addEvent({
        id: createEventId(),
        title,
        start: selectInfo.startStr,
        end: selectInfo.endStr,
        allDay: selectInfo.allDay,
      });
    }
  };

  handleEventClick = (clickInfo) => {
    if (
      confirm(
        `Are you sure you want to delete the event '${clickInfo.event.title}'`
      )
    ) {
      clickInfo.event.remove();
    }
  };

  handleEvents = (events) => {
    this.setState({
      currentEvents: events,
    });
  };
}

function renderEventContent(eventInfo) {
  return (
    <>
      <b>{eventInfo.timeText}</b>
      <i>{eventInfo.event.title}</i>
    </>
  );
}

function renderSidebarEvent(event) {
  return (
    <li key={event.id}>
      <b>
        {formatDate(event.start, {
          year: "numeric",
          month: "short",
          day: "numeric",
        })}
      </b>
      <i>{event.title}</i>
    </li>
  );
}
```

This is where I am making a get call. I am trying to replace hardcoded events in INITIAL_EVENTS and replace them with the values in the database but I'm not able to map the database values with the event attributes.

```
-----Util.js-----
let eventGuid = 129;
let todayStr = new Date().toISOString().replace(/T.*$/, ""); // YYYY-MM-DD of today

initialEvents ={
  async function() {
    const response = await fetch(
    "http://localhost:2999/getall");
    const data = await response.json();
    console.log(data.length);
    console.log(data);
  }
}
export const INITIAL_EVENTS = [ 
  {
    id: createEventId(),
    title: "All-day event",
    start: todayStr,
  },
  {
    id: createEventId(),
    title: "Timed event",
    start: todayStr + "T12:00:00",
  },
];

export function createEventId() {
  return String(eventGuid++);
}
```

`

Comment: "initialEvents" can only accept a static array of events. It's not updatable. It's only designed for the "initial" events, i.e. the first ones to be displayed, not any extra ones or updates. If you want to specify an updateable event feed then use "events" and read https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed

Answer (score 0):

This is one solution to dynamically populate data from the database in the calendar.
I declared state variable - DBEvents : [], called function calendarValue() in place of INITIAL_EVENTS which makes rest call to fetch data.

```
----Event.jsx-----
import React from "react";
import FullCalendar, { formatDate } from "@fullcalendar/react";
import dayGridPlugin from "@fullcalendar/daygrid";
import timeGridPlugin from "@fullcalendar/timegrid";
import interactionPlugin from "@fullcalendar/interaction";
import { INITIAL_EVENTS, createEventId } from "./Util";

export default class EventCalander extends React.Component {
  state = {
    weekendsVisible: true,
    currentEvents: [],
    DBEvents:[],
  };

 calendarValue = (events) => {
    const response = fetch(
      "http://localhost:2999/get");
      events = response.json();
    this.setState({
      DBEvents: events,
    });
    return this.state.DBEvents;
          }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="demo-app">
        {this.renderSidebar()}
        <div className="demo-app-main">
          <FullCalendar
            plugins={[dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, interactionPlugin]}
            headerToolbar={{
              left: "prev,next today",
              center: "title",
              right: "dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay",
              
            }}
            initialView="timeGridWeek"
            editable={true}
            selectable={true}
            selectMirror={true}
            dayMaxEvents={true}
            weekends={this.state.weekendsVisible}
            initialEvents={ () => this.calendarValue() } // alternatively, use the `events` setting to fetch from a feed
            select={this.handleDateSelect}
            eventContent={renderEventContent} // custom render function
            eventClick={this.handleEventClick}
            eventsSet={this.handleEvents} // called after events are initialized/added/changed/removed
            /* you can update a remote database when these fire: 
            eventAdd={async function()}
            eventChange={function()}
            eventRemove={function() }*/
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

  renderSidebar() {
    return (
      <div className="demo-app-sidebar">
         <div className='demo-app-sidebar-section'>
            <h2>Instructions</h2>
            <ul>
              <li>Select dates and you will be prompted to create a new event</li>
              <li>Drag, drop, and resize events</li>
              <li>Click an event to delete it</li>
            </ul>
          </div> 
        <div className="demo-app-sidebar-section">
           <label>
              <input
                type='checkbox'
                checked={this.state.weekendsVisible}
                onChange={this.handleWeekendsToggle}
              ></input>
              toggle weekends
            </label> 
        </div>
        <div className="demo-app-sidebar-section">
          <h2>All Events ({this.state.currentEvents.length})</h2>
          <ul>{this.state.currentEvents.map(renderSidebarEvent)}</ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

  handleWeekendsToggle = () => {
    this.setState({
      weekendsVisible: !this.state.weekendsVisible,
    });
  };

  handleDateSelect = (selectInfo) => {
    let title = prompt("Please enter a new title for your event");
    let calendarApi = selectInfo.view.calendar;

    calendarApi.unselect(); // clear date selection

    if (title) {
      calendarApi.addEvent({
        id: createEventId(),
        title,
        start: selectInfo.startStr,
        end: selectInfo.endStr,
        allDay: selectInfo.allDay,
      });
    }
  };

  handleEventClick = (clickInfo) => {
    if (
      confirm(
        `Are you sure you want to delete the event '${clickInfo.event.title}'`
      )
    ) {
      clickInfo.event.remove();
    }
  };

  handleEvents = (events) => {
    this.setState({
      currentEvents: events,
    });
  };
}

function renderEventContent(eventInfo) {
  return (
    <>
      <b>{eventInfo.timeText}</b>
      <i>{eventInfo.event.title}</i>
    </>
  );
}

function renderSidebarEvent(event) {
  return (
    <li key={event.id}>
      <b>
        {formatDate(event.start, {
          year: "numeric",
          month: "short",
          day: "numeric",
        })}
      </b>
      <i>{event.title}</i>
    </li>
  );
}
```